# How can I play Descent 3?

Tags: descent-3

How can I download or play Descent 3 - I have an old Xbox, a macbook and access to Windows 7.  I have done a search online and can't find software or downloads

Thanks

Comment: We're not about finding games for you.  It's up to you to do that.  We can help you get it *running*, but finding is out.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding a specific game somewhere.  Arqade is not an asset location service.

Comment: you can withdraw -

Answer (score 2):

http://www.gog.com has this game in it's catalog.

You can purchase it (and instantly download it) [here](http://www.gog.com/game/descent_3_expansion).